# Rule exceptions in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created page that every new user is redirected to upon visit, it sets a cookie that allows access to the rest of my site. I want to add exception to this rule for some sites and their bots:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://www.site1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http://www.site2.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot2 [NC]
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !yes=1 [NC]
RewriteRule !^(script1.php|script2.php)$ script2.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As you can see, if the cookie doesn't exist or !=1 every user is redirected to script2.php.

I wrote some exceptions, but sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

I've made an error somewhere, but i don't see it.

Can you help me with this? Thank you for you time.

Comment: I'd rather use [L] instead of [S=1]. Secondly, I would do a external redirect to script2.php, so it's not cached (incorrectly). So use [R,L] instead of just [L] on your last rule.

Comment: @Gerben: I have followed your instructions and it works perfectly now. Could you post it as answer so i can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use `[L]` instead of `[S=1]`.

Secondly, I would do a external redirect to script2.php, so it's not cached (incorrectly). So use `[R,L]` instead of just `[L]` on your last rule.